# APA referencing style (7th edition) in overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Please how do I get  APA referencing Style (7th edition) in overleaf and to change the the bibliography name to References. The below codes are not giving the results

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\printbibliography{}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
```

Comment: You're right, your code does not give any results because it is not compilable and therefore no propper MWE. Concerning your problem of renaming: Try to *first* rename your bibliography and *then* print it.

Answer (score 3):

With the biblatex package, you can use the `title=...` key to change the title of your  references:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth:ct}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```